# Why are airplane tyres slightly conducting?

Tags: material-science, conductors

As per my knowledge, airplane tyres are slightly conducting, but I do not know why.

I think it is for ground conductance but can you explain please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think it is for ground conductance

[Partly so.](https://www.goodyearaviation.com/resources/pdf/aviation-tire-care-2020.pdf)

> Tires dissipate some static electricity in service but this
> conductivity will change with the cleanliness of the tire surface,
> atmospheric conditions and runway surface. Since this discharge rate
> is variable and not very controllable, the tire cannot be counted on
> to dissipate static electricity. If there is any question about static
> charge build-up, the aircraft must be grounded by mechanical means.

Answer (score 1):

They are conductive to prevent the buildup of electricity. Since there is a great deal of friction during takeoff and landing, an insulating tire like that on a typical car would build up a large charge, which could discharge into the body of the plane and have devastating consequences for the sensitive advanced electronics inside. Said electronics are all electrically shielded, but it's not worth taking on additional risk by building up a charge and testing their shielding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good answer for you. I had heard the same and figured google would know
https://monroeaerospace.com/blog/why-airplane-tires-are-made-of-condu

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/417120)